# set the radio button checked automatically based on that data form other class

Tags: java, android

i want to use the battery percentage obtained from the broadcast receiver
in setting the radio button automatically based on the percentage of a battery to go to the other activity
i have  radio buttons (>20%) (20-40%) (40-60%) (60-80%) (80-90%) (>90%)

```
  int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
  int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,-1);
  float batteryper = (level/(float)scale)*100;
  txtlevel.setText("battery level :"+batteryper+"%");
```

Comment: If you want to do it in real-time, you need to use the Observer pattern

Comment: I can get the value of battery percentage easily 
so based on that value cant we use just if statements and make it checked automatically if the given percentage in this range check this radio button or else this radio button some thing like that

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `radioButton.setChecked(true);` or `radiobutton.setSelected(true);`

```
 int i = 10;


        if(i>0 && i<=20){
        }else if(i>20 && i<=40) {
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }else if(i>40 && i<=60){
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }else if(i>60 & i<=80){
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }else if(i>80 && i<=100){
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
```

Comment: how will it help me?

Comment: based on the selected radio button now,
how can i use this selected radio button to go to new activity

Comment: use INTENT to start a new activity **startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));**